# How to fail a Cucumber scenario without java.lang.AssertionError

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, assertion, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I am using Cucumber JVM to write my test cases with Selenide. If I use TestNG to assert, the failures are shown in the following format:

```
Step failed
java.lang.AssertionError: No HTTP Response Received: CODE=500;STATUS=Internal Server Error
```

I would like to fail the test without including java.lang.AssertionError by showing only the String message that I want in the System console/log/HTML reports. Cucumber already does that I believe whenever it runs into any unexpected error or webdriver exceptions. Is there any class or interface that can be leveraged to achieve that?

Answer (score -1):

You can use

import cucumber.api.Fail

Fail.fail("Expected Error Message")

Comment: In Cucumber 7.11.1, I am not able to locate this method.